# How do I avoid splatter when frying ginger garlic paste?

Tags: garlic, ginger

I see in all cookery shows that they use ginger garlic paste with ease. When I bought a sachet of the same and put it in oil, it spluttered so much that all of my stove surface ended up oily. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a splatter screen? You place it over the frying pan while cooking and it will prevent any oil or other substances from splattering out of the pan and onto the stove. Something like this: [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81D4-YeDBtL.*SL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81D4-YeDBtL._SL1500_.jpg)

Alternatively you could try lowering the temperature you are cooking at.

Comment: Hmmm.. Not a bad idea.. I was thinking more on resolution on garlic paste.. Because when I use crushed ginger garlic instead of the packet, it doesn't create so much of splatter.